# Do Android device model variants have the same exact hardware?

Tags: android, android-hardware

I'm trying to better identify malicious users devices without using sensible data nor sign-in nor requesting dangerous permissions.

With the latest Android privacy updates it is impossibile to retrieve any non-resettable hardware identifier. So I want to associate less precise device info, like the build model variant, to other types of data (location, ip address...) to increase the confidence of identifying a specific device.

Every device model (Galaxy S10 for example) has different variants (SM-G970x, SM-G973x, SM-G975x, SM-G977x). And you can retrieve the variant like this.

```
val modelWithVariant = Build.DISPLAY
```

My question is: can I increase even more my level of confidence looking at specific device hardware information (of course not RAM and storage that are straightforward to retrieve)? I mean, a device build variant has for sure the exact same hardware? Or maybe the hardware can be slightly different?

I'm not looking at Secure.ANDROID_ID, WIDEVINE_ID, Firebase ID or other resettable IDs.

Thank you.

Comment: It varies widely across the board, Some hauwei devices like lets say the p8 Lite has 2 version the original and the 2017 version SO with the original one some models has NFC some do not, the 2017 version depending on the model the camera arrays are diffrent (picture quality are the same ) but they are using diffrent camera optics etc. depending on the model, There are many other cases with all manufacturers where depending on the model of the device the internals might be a bit diffrent like chips with idiffrent models etc.so its difficult to say

Comment: Thank you @RubenMeiring. But I suppose different year model have different variants. I'm interested to know if the same model variant, let's say SM-G970F, might have slightly differences in hardware (sensors, battery, other). Maybe this is impossible because a variant by definition has a predefined set of hardware that is immutable. Thanks.

Comment: Oh Now I understand, there won't be differences in hardware if the models are the same, there might be like a 1 percentile where there are diffrences but 99% of the time it will be the same if the model is the same (identical models from diffrent countries might have some diffrences)